# angular 6 application and routing to next page displays bottom of current page

Tags: angular

Hello I am having very small angular 6 application, I am using angulalr route to route to next page, say thank you page but when I click on next button on my home page it is showing next page at bottom of current page, however it appends /thankyou at URL.
app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ThankYou } from './thank-you-page/thankyou';


export const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'RedirectingPage', component: RedirectingPage}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
on HomeComponent.ts file on button click I have below code.

  modal.componentInstance.option1
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((modalInstance: NgbActiveModal) => {
        console.log("insided routing thank you page")
        modalInstance.dismiss();
        this.router.navigate(['../RedirectingPage']);
      });
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    ThankYou,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  exports:[AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[ModalComponent]
})
```

Please help

Comment: So you only have one route? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. There are too many unknowns in wat you posted.

Comment: Yes, on click of button I would like to move to next page which says your details are submitted.

Comment: There can not be a "next page" if there is only one route. To have a "next page", you would need the current page to be displayed on a route, too. If it's not displayed on a specific route, then it's always displayed.

Comment: I did not get you, if you can explain a little bit.

Comment: You would get me if you posted a complete example reproducing the problem. That would allow me to explain what is wrong in that complete example, and to post the code necessary to fix it. You want to make the "home" page/route disappear, and instead display the "thankyou" page/route. But you don't have a "home" page/route. So it can't disappear.

Comment: How to add current page to route? if you can help me with that.

Comment: Please note that I am running on localhost:4200

Comment: The same way you defined your "thank you" route: you add a route, with a path, and a component. And that component is the Home component. The Home component will thus be displayed when you're at the path of the home page.

Comment: export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Register', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'RedirectingPage', component: RedirectingPage}
];

Comment: The APp component is the root component. It is always displayed. It should only contain what is comon to all pages. You need another component: HomeCOmponent or RegisterComponent, containing what is didplayed on the home page/register page only, and that HomeComponent/RegisterComponent must be the component of the home/register route.

Comment: I only have AppComponent and RedirectingComponent which is thank you page. on my AppComponent user clicks on button and that redirects to redirecting page which is static page.

Comment: { path: 'home', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'ThankYou', component: ThankYou },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: now page displays two time, I moved content of appComponent to RegisterComponent, please advise

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: it worked, in app.component.html I just removed template part of register component and put the <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

it worked, in app.component.html I just removed template part of register component and put the

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Created separate register component and in routing.module.ts I put down below code:

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'home', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'ThankYou', component: ThankYou },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

];
```